# Magento 1.9.1.0 password is blank in "new customer" email from front end

Tags: magento

I just imastalled new magebto CE 1.9.1.0 and I found the password field is blank in the mail that sent to customers while creating a new account on magento website. I'm using default Magento theme with default configuration.

However it's working fine in Magento CE 1.9.0.1

Any idea ?

Answer (score 2):

It is an security enhancement in release version 1.9.1.0

- Customer passwords are no longer stored in clear text during registration.

See also Release Notes of version 1.9.1.0 http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/ce19-later-release-notes#ce19-1910